# How to use 1 SQL query related to date and time in order to compare value difference

Tags: sql

```html
SELECT c.treatment_category, a.treatment_id, MAX(a.counts - b.counts) AS ReviewDifference        
        
        
FROM         
        
(SELECT treatment_id, COUNT(treatment_id) AS counts        
FROM review        
WHERE DATE(review.created) BETWEEN DATE(TIMESTAMP'2016-01-01 00:00:00.0') AND DATE(TIMESTAMP'2016-12-31 23:59:59.999')        
GROUP BY treatment_id) a        
        
LEFT JOIN        
        
(SELECT treatment_id, COUNT(treatment_id)        
FROM review        
WHERE DATE(review.created) BETWEEN DATE(TIMESTAMP'2015-01-01 00:00:00.0') AND DATE(TIMESTAMP'2015-12-31 23:59:59.999')        
GROUP BY treatment_id) b        
        
ON a = b        
        
LEFT JOIN        
        
(SELECT t.treatment_category AS category, r.treatment_id AS number        
FROM treatment t        
LEFT JOIN review r        
ON t.treatment_id = r.treatment_id        
GROUP BY category, number) c        
        
ON b.treatment_id = c.number        
        
GROUP BY a.treatment_id, c.treatment_category        
ORDER BY ReviewDifference DESC        
LIMIT 1;
```

I need some hints or simpler query on how to do this question since it is related to date and time. Thank you.

1. What treatment category has seen the biggest increase in reviews from 2015 to 2016?

Please see below for the tables.

[image: sample.png]

I have provided my code snippet and I would like to find a simpler and cleaner way on writing the code.

Comment: #1, you need `group by` similar to #2 but without order or limit

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT t.treatment_id, t.treatment_name, 
        COUNT( CASE WHEN YEAR(created) = 2016 THEN r.review_id END)
      - COUNT( CASE WHEN YEAR(created) = 2015 THEN r.review_id END) as review_count
 FROM treatments t
 JOIN reviews r
   ON t.treatment_id = r.treatment_id
 GROUP BY t.treatment_id, t.treatment_name, 
 ORDER BY review_count DESC
```